# Link Sleuth - How to show origination page of broken external links

Tags: hyperlink, linkchecker, xenu

I'm using Link Sleuth to find broken external links on our site. It does a great job only I cannot figure out how to get it to show which page the links originate from.

The report provides the broken link but not the page where it lives. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Select a resulting external link and hit Alt + Enter